# When should I assert the actions of the SUT?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

Consider the following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void Success()
{
  var userID = 5;
  var user = new User();
  var dataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
  dataAccess.Setup(x => x.GetUser(userID)).Returns(user).Verifiable();
  var sut = new UserController(dataAccess.Object);

  var returnedUser = sut.GetUser(userID);

  Assert.AreSame(user, returnedUser);
  dataAccess.Verify(x => x.GetUser(userID), Times.Once());
}
```

Recent reading has suggested that I should only use the mock to provide the user and there should be a single assert (the AreSame one). Apparently the ideal unit test shouldn't worry about verifying the sut's behaviour.

More like this:

```
[Test]
public void Success()
{
  var userID = 5;
  var user = new User();
  var dataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
  dataAccess.Setup(x => x.GetUser(userID)).Returns(user);
  var sut = new UserController(dataAccess.Object);

  var returnedUser = sut.GetUser(userID);

  Assert.AreSame(user, returnedUser);
}
```

Is this simplified test better? Should Unit Tests assert the behaviour of methods they call or just the results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [State/Interaction testing and confusion on mixing (or abusing) them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300221/state-interaction-testing-and-confusion-on-mixing-or-abusing-them)

Comment: And this is a good background article to read: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One basic idea is to have **only one Assert in test**. So maybe you should consider two tests here. The first value-based test is important. The second interaction test is probably not suitable in this case. According to Roy Osherove: 'You use interaction testing when calling another object is the end result of specific unit of work.'.

Example:

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UserControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetUser_WhenCalled_ReturnsUserSameAsDataAccess()
        {
            // Arrange
            const int userID = 5;
            User expectedUser = new User();

            Mock<IDataAccess> dataAccessStub = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
            dataAccessStub.Setup(x => x.GetUser(userID)).Returns(expectedUser);
            UserController controller = new UserController(dataAccessStub.Object);

            // Act
            User actualUser = controller.GetUser(userID);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreSame(expectedUser, actualUser);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetUser_WhenCalled_GetUserOnDataAccessIsCalledOnce()
        {
            // Arrange
            const int userID = 5;
            const int getUserCallsCountExpected = 1;
            int getUserCallsCount = 0;

            Mock<IDataAccess> dataAccessMock = new Mock<IDataAccess>();
            dataAccessMock.Setup(x => x.GetUser(userID)).Callback(() => getUserCallsCount++);
            UserController controller = new UserController(dataAccessMock.Object);

            // Act
            controller.GetUser(userID);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(getUserCallsCountExpected, getUserCallsCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree to the first test. But I always struggle to appreciate what value the second test adds? Isn't it testing the internal implementation of the API? Will this test be resilient to refactoring? Shouldn't a unit test continue to pass as long as the public behavior doesn't change?

Comment: @Amol yes I think you are right, the second test is probably not suitable in this case. I edited the answer.