# Unit Test Assert.AreEqual failed

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, assert

I have a unit test for a method which gets an object from a collection. This keeps failing and I cannot see why, so I have created a very simple test below to create 2 supplier object and test they are equal to see if I can spot the problem in my test of my code. But this test again is failing. Can anyone see or explain why?

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetSupplierTest2()
    {
        Supplier expected = new Supplier();
        expected.SupplierID = 32532;
        expected.SupplierName = "Test 1"

        Supplier actual = new Supplier();
        actual.SupplierID = 32532;
        actual.SupplierName = "Test 1"

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

But if I test the individual properties of the objects the test passes...

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetSupplierTest2()
    {
        Supplier expected = new Supplier();
        expected.SupplierID = 32532;
        expected.SupplierName = "Test 1"

    Supplier actual = new Supplier();
        actual.SupplierID = 32532;
        actual.SupplierName = "Test 1"

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SupplierID , actual.SupplierID );
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SupplierName , actual.SupplierName );
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare two different instances of Supplier, and want them to be considered equal when certain properties have the same value, you have to override the `Equals` method on `Supplier` and compare those properties in the method.

You can read more about the Equals method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Example implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Supplier)
    {
        Supplier other = (Supplier) obj;
        return Equals(other.SupplierID, this.SupplierID) && Equals(other.SupplierName, this.SupplierName);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that you'll also get a compiler warning that you have to implement GetHashCode as well, that could be as simple as this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return SupplierID;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on overiding the Equals method please?

Answer (score 22):

As every other answer says the issue is that you're trying to compare instances of `Supplier` [probably] without overriding `Equals` method. **But I do not think you should override `Equals` for test purposes** since it may affect production code or you may need another `Equals` logic in production code.

Instead you should either assert each member one by one as you do it in first sample (if you do not have a lot of places where you want to compare entire object) or encapsulate this comparison logic in some class and use this class:

```
static class SupplierAllFieldsComparer
{
    public static void AssertAreEqual(Supplier expected, Supplier actual)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SupplierID , actual.SupplierID );
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SupplierName , actual.SupplierName );            
    }
}
```

// Test code:

```
SupplierAllFieldsComparer.AssertAreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: I fully agree. I suggest reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180044/should-one-override-equals-method-for-asserting-the-object-equality-in-a-unit-tes

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation of `Object.Equals` for reference types (ie. classes) is "Reference Equality": are the two objects actually the *same* instance. It doesn't compare the values of fields.

Either (as others have shown) override `Equals` to give "Value Equality". In this caseyou must also override `GetHashCode` (so containers work), and should override `operator ==`.

Alternatively accept that most entities should have reference equality (two suppliers with the same name are not always the same organisation) and actually use the properties directly.

Answer (score 2):

You compare 2 different instances of the Supplier type, that's why Assert fail.

If you want to Supplier are equals say (by their **Id**) you can override *Equals* method, here very over simpled example, :D.

```
public class Supplier
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public bool Equals(Supplier other)
    {
        if(other == null) return false;
        return other.id == id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (Supplier)) return false;
        return Equals((Supplier) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return id;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would you unit test a scenario like this? Is it the right approach to just compare the values of each property or is there a method to compare an object with an object?

Comment: you could override the Equals function

Comment: Can you expand on this a little please?

Answer (score 1):

When testing the individual properties, you compare the string/integer values.  They are equal, and so the tests pass.

When testing the parent objects, you compare only the two container structures of type Supplier - and even though those may hold equal property values, they are not equal:  Since you are instantiating two separate objects, they do not reside at the same address in memory.

Comment: Thanks, so how would you unit test a scenario like this? Is there a method to compare an object with an object?

Comment: As the other two posters have suggested, you can override the Equals method of the Supplier type and have it compare the individual property values.  See this tutorial, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
//Given the following structure and an instance value, targetObj...

class BaseType
{
   private FeatureType Feature_1;
}

class TargetType : BaseType 
{
  ...
}

TargetType targetObj = new TargetType();

//...a private feature in a specific base class can be accessed as follows

PrivateType typeCast = new PrivateType(typeof( BaseType ));

PrivateObject privateObj = new PrivateObject(targetObj, typeCast);

//...and values can be retrieved and set as follows....

privateObj.SetField("Feature_1", (FeatureType) newValue );

FeatureType result = (FeatureType) privateObj.GetField("Feature_1");
```

/*
With respect to the controversy around accessing private fields in unit tests, I believe it should never be used unless absolutely neccessary (i.e. time and expense management issues).
*/