# Json is not recognised as an object in my unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nunit, json.net

Hi I Return a JsonResult in my MVC Controller and I want to unit test the result returned. 
My Controller code is as follows

```
        return Json(new
        {
            error,
            viewModel,
            contextId = viewModel.ContextId
        });
```

and my unit test code is

```
        var expectedJson = Json(new
        {
            error,
            viewModel,
            contextId = viewModel.ContextId
        });
```

I have added the nuget packages JSon.Net & JSon-js json2 which are both in my Web Package. I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

my using directives for my controller are

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ionic.Zip;
using ReferenceData.Web.Services;
using ReferenceData.Web.ViewModels;
```

and the using directives for my unit test are

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
```

The controller method returns a JsonResult. In my Unit test I am trying to create an object that I can compare with the JsonResult.Data.

```
// act
JsonResult response = controller.doSomething()
// assert
Assert.AreEqual(response.data, expectedJson)
```

Hopefully It is just one of those things that a fresh set of eyes will help with. I'm new to using Json the original controller was written by someone else I am just testing it.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: What's the code of your unit test?

Comment: @SamLeach the exact error is "Cannot Resolve Symbol Json". It really looks like something to do with a missing reference.

Comment: @Raubi the second block of code is where I am trying to manually create  some Json in my unit test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my mistake was using

```
Var x = Json(new ...
```

In my test I should have declared it like this

```
        var expectedJson = new
        {
            error,
            viewModel,
            contextId = viewModel.ContextId
        };
```

Json is a method that is inherited from Controller, this is why it would not work in my unit tests. Then to gain access to the elements in the JsonResult.data I did this

```
dynamic response = controller.doSomething() as dynamic;
```

By using a dynamic it gives me access to the elements in the Json and I can test against them directly. This is still not completly working but I'm not sure if it is a problem with my test or the code I'm testing

Answer (score 0):

You want to bet using `JsonResult` in your unit tests.

```
JsonResult result = controller.ReturnSomeJson() as JsonResult;
```

see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/25/unit-testing-the-mvc-jsonresult.aspx) article.

Comment: hi I have just checked the references for the unit test package and System.Web.MVC is there and I have it in my using directives for my cs file

Comment: Sorry I should have probably explained that my controller method does actually return a JsonResult already. I am tring to create something that I can compare with the JsonResult.data

Comment: Test the data, not the Json object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Assert.AreEqual` you should override `Equal` to compare objects: [Unit Test Assert.AreEqual failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328218/unit-test-assert-areequal-failed)

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do this is by using reflection as you are returning anonymous types.

```
var result = this.Controller.Method() as JsonResult;

var viewmodel = result.Data.GetType().Getproperty("viewModel").GetValue(result.Data,null);    

Assert.AreEqual(viewmodel, expectedviewmodelValue);
```

Note: Debug and see what is there inside `result`, by placing BreakPoint and when hit, select "result", right click, select "`Quick Watch`". Expand to `result.Data`. See the value property inside and the type. Then modify `.GetProperty("HERE")`.
I am not sure with what is `return JSON(...)` but `return JsonResult`, is what usually used.