# Equals is used. GetHashCode is not

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I have implemented the class below:

```
public class carComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
    {
        public bool Equals(Car car1, Car car2)
        {
                if (car1 == null || car2 == null)
                    return false;

                return (car1.description == car2.description);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Car car)
        {
            unchecked 
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 29 + car.id.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 29 + car.description.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }

    }
```

Now see this:

```
Car p1 = new Car() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "Test1" };
        Car p2 = new Car() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "Test1" };
        Car p3 = new Car() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "Test1" };
        Car p4 = new Car() { id = Guid.NewGuid(), description = "Test1" };
        var hash = new HashSet<Car>();
        hash.Add(p1);
        hash.Add(p2);

        var hash2 = new HashSet<Car>();
        hash2.Add(p3);
        hash2.Add(p4);

        var carComparer = new CarComparer();
        Assert.That(hash, Is.EquivalentTo(hash2).Using(carComparer));
```

I put breakpoints in .equals and .hashcode.  Equals is used; but GetHashCode is not.  Why?

Comment: What is `Car` (and/or `car`, are they equivalent)? Where exactly did you expect `GetHashCode` to be called? Why?

Comment: At what point was equals used? Putting your code into Linqpad doesn't call either method for me which is to be expected since you aren't telling the hashset to use your comparer. If I do `var hash = new HashSet<Car>(new carComparer());` then it calls `GetHashCode` twice, I assume once for each object that you add...

Comment: And why should it be used? You are not calling it anywhere. You are calling GetHashCode() ion car.id and car.description, but not on car.

Comment: @VDN, I am calling it in the Assert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing two `HashSet` using NUnit `Is.EquivalentTo`. There is no reason for it to call `GetHashCode` - it basically compares two collections for equality of its members. That's why `GetHashCode` is never called and `Equals` is called to compare two items from different `HashSet`s for equality. Your hashsets could as well be lists or any other enumerable - that doesn't change anything when comparing two collections.

You might expect `GetHashCode` to be called when you add item to `HashSet` - but it's not so, because at this point your `carComparer` is not yet known - you don't pass it to `HashSet` constructor. If you will do it like this:

```
var hash = new HashSet<Car>(new carComparer());
```

Then `GetHashCode` would be called when you add new item to corresponding `HashSet`.

Comment: When is GetHashCode called? Is it called when an item is added to the collection or when the .equals is called.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you think of the quality of my hashcode? I used the answer to this question as a template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180044/should-one-override-equals-method-for-asserting-the-object-equality-in-a-unit-te      +1 for the clarification, which makes sense.

Comment: Looks ok for me. Note that you might override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` of `car` object itself, then you won't need to have pass specific comparer every time.

Comment: it is used by a unit test only.  Therefore I do not think it is a good idea to override Car.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's quite strange that cars are considered equal by one condition in unit test and by other condition in production. But if that makes sense to you - why not?

Comment: Also is it "ok" to use the id (GUID) as part of a hashcode comparison? Notice that I do not use id in the .equals. All the examples I look at never use the id.  Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977: What you should be doing is working out what you consider equality to be first and then building up a hashcode from the fields in that equality. In your case for example your hash code is broken because two cars with the same description but different ids will be considered equal by your equality method but will generate different hashcodes. For your equality method your hashcode could just return `description.GetHashCode()`. However I assume that in fact different ids make different cars...

Comment: Also a note on your hashcode function - I'm not sure why you have the initial value of 17 and then do a multiply of it by 29. The only difference between what you have now and an initial seed of 0 is that your final hashcode will be 29*29*17 higher than if your initial seed was 0. This will be a constant increase so feels a little pointless to me.

Comment: As almost always with SO questions - you should post what problem are you solving, not just some random code.

Comment: @Chris, please see the answer from Jon Skeet in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode.  It tells you why I have used 17 and 29.

Comment: @w0051977: Thanks. Will ask Jon. :)

Comment: @Chris he multiplies with addition, it is not the same as just 29*29*17

Comment: @evk: It is... In the above if the two hashcodes are a,b and the initial value is i then the hashcode is: (29 * (i*29+a))+b = which equals i*29*29+a*29+b. Or am I screwing up the maths here?

Comment: I've decided to just ask a new question about it in case anybody is interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754687/why-is-an-initial-prime-used-in-gethashcode-implementations

Answer (score 2):

GetHashCode is typically used in  a hash-table-lookup.

The `GetHashCode` does not have to be guaranteed unique and therefor is not a valid `IsEqual` test.

For the GetHashCode to be used, use this constructor of the HashSet:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx

So in order to use the `GetHashCode` method, you'll need to use:

```
var hash = new HashSet<Car>(carComparer);
```

Note that the hash will be verified when adding your object to the hashset.

The Comparer is then used in the `HashSet.Add` method, within this call:

```
private int InternalGetHashCode(T item)
{
  if ((object) item == null)
    return 0;

  //this._comparer is set during the constructor call
  return this._comparer.GetHashCode(item) & int.MaxValue;
}
```

For obvious reasons this makes the `Comparer` a read only property.

**So, to sum up;**

The `GetHashCode` is not used because, since it is typically used in a hash-table-lookup-creation, you'll need to provide it to the HashSet before you start adding items.

The `IsEqual` is used due to obvious reasons; and if it's not: see @dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the question. He is putting things in a `HashSet` which is why he expects `GetHashCode` to be called but it isn't. Your answer doesn't seem to address this point, instead talking generalities about the two methods...

Comment: But, the `IEqualityComparer` is not bound to the HashSet in  any way while it is while testing equality.

Comment: Right, carComparer is used in Add method only if it is passed in HashSet constructor.

Comment: @Chris: Although you had a point about missing a crucial part of the question, I don't think your point is valid since the hashset is not bound to the comparer which is crucial while adding to (and therefor creating) the hashtable. Anyhow, I updated the answer with more details, I hope you will reconsider your comment ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: I do think the answer is much better now, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the algorithm used in `IsEquivalent` to decide equivalency: the implementation constructs what they call a "collection tally" object from the collection that you expect, and then try removing items of the actual collection from it one-by-one:

```
public bool TryRemove(IEnumerable c) {
    foreach (object o in c)
        if (!TryRemove(o))
            return false;
    return true;
}

public bool TryRemove(object o) {
    for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
        if (ItemsEqual(list[index], o)) {
            list.RemoveAt(index);
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

You can see that NUnit uses a relatively inefficient O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm instead of constructing a hash set for O(n) efficiency. This would matter for larger sets, but since a typical collection in a unit test has only a few items, there would be no noticeable difference.

`ItemsEqual` uses `Equals` from the equality comparer, but it has no need for hash code functionality ([source code](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/CollectionTally.cs)).

Comment: Nice detail about the `collection tally`.